# Python - Calendar / Date Library for Arithmetic Date Operations

Tags: python, date, datetime, calendar, format

This is for Python: 
I need a library that is able to do arithmetic operations on dates while taking into account the duration of a month and or year.

***For example, say I add a value of "1 day" to 3/31/2020, the result of should return: 
1 + 3/31/2020 = 4/1/2020.***

I also would need to be able to convert this to datetime format, and extract day, year and month.

Does a library like this exist?

Comment: `import datetime` ?

Comment: Would this take into account Month/Day constraints? I am currently using an API and have logic built in to increment (+1,+2, etc) within a datetime function (year, month, day +2). The issue is that sometimes the values that are being passed to the application are in violation of the Month Day constraints, for example if I did + 2 days on March 31, it would feed it (2020, 3, 33). It doesn't seem that datetime supports the automatic logic of converting this over into the month of April, (2020, 4, 2).

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

tday = datetime.date.today()  # create today

print("Today:", tday)

""" create one week time duration """

oneWeek = datetime.timedelta(days=7)

""" create 1 day and 1440 minutes of time duraiton """

eightDays = datetime.timedelta(days=7, minutes=1440)

print("A week later than today:", tday + oneWeek)  # print today +7 days
```

And the output to this code snippet is:

```
Today: 2020-03-25
A week later than today: 2020-04-01
>>>
```

As you see, it takes month overflows into account and turns March to April. datetime module has lots of things, I don't know all its attributes well and haven't used for a long time. However, I believe you can find nice documentation or tutorials on the web.

You definitely can create any specific date(there should be some constraints though) instead of today by supplying day, month and year info. I just don't remember how to do it.